# CUDA CXX CMAKE: nvlink error : Undefined reference

Tags: c++, cmake, cuda, linker-errors

so I am working on this for almost a day now and I can not figure it out on my own. For a large CUDA and CXX project, I am using CMake for dependency handling/compilation settings. I am working on Windows 11 using MSVC2019. The idea is that I have multiple modules i.e. libraries with host and device code that are linked to executables in the apps folder. However when I try to compile the executable there is a linking error from CUDA even though (I think) I have linked all required repos. On the other hand, the libraries (which all depend on each other) compile just fine using the same settings.

The complete build and error log is the following:

```
[main] Configuring folder: fix_cuda_linker 
[driver] Removing c:/artemis/artemis_tests/fix_cuda_linker/build/CMakeCache.txt
[driver] Removing c:\artemis\artemis_tests\fix_cuda_linker\build\CMakeFiles
[proc] Executing command: "C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.EXE" --no-warn-unused-cli -DCMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS:BOOL=TRUE -Sc:/artemis/artemis_tests/fix_cuda_linker -Bc:/artemis/artemis_tests/fix_cuda_linker/build -G "Visual Studio 16 2019" -T host=x64 -A x64
[cmake] Not searching for unused variables given on the command line.
[cmake] -- Selecting Windows SDK version 10.0.19041.0 to target Windows 10.0.22000.
[cmake] -- The CUDA compiler identification is NVIDIA 11.5.50
[cmake] -- The CXX compiler identification is MSVC 19.29.30143.0
[cmake] -- The C compiler identification is MSVC 19.29.30143.0
[cmake] -- Detecting CUDA compiler ABI info
[cmake] -- Detecting CUDA compiler ABI info - done
[cmake] -- Check for working CUDA compiler: C:/Program Files/NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit/CUDA/v11.5/bin/nvcc.exe - skipped
[cmake] -- Detecting CUDA compile features
[cmake] -- Detecting CUDA compile features - done
[cmake] -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
[cmake] -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
[cmake] -- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.29.30133/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe - skipped
[cmake] -- Detecting CXX compile features
[cmake] -- Detecting CXX compile features - done
[cmake] -- Detecting C compiler ABI info
[cmake] -- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
[cmake] -- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.29.30133/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe - skipped
[cmake] -- Detecting C compile features
[cmake] -- Detecting C compile features - done
[cmake] -- Configuring done
[cmake] -- Generating done
[cmake] -- Build files have been written to: C:/artemis/artemis_tests/fix_cuda_linker/build
```

and

```
[main] Building folder: fix_cuda_linker clean
[build] Starting build
[proc] Executing command: "C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.EXE" --build c:/artemis/artemis_tests/fix_cuda_linker/build --config Debug --target clean -j 18 --
[build] Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 16.11.2+f32259642 for .NET Framework
[build] Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
[build] 
[build] Build finished with exit code 0
[main] Building folder: fix_cuda_linker 
[build] Starting build
[proc] Executing command: "C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.EXE" --build c:/artemis/artemis_tests/fix_cuda_linker/build --config Debug --target ALL_BUILD -j 18 --
[build] Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 16.11.2+f32259642 for .NET Framework
[build] Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
[build] 
[build]   Checking Build System
[build]   Building Custom Rule C:/artemis/artemis_tests/fix_cuda_linker/modules/func1/CMakeLists.txt
[build]   Compiling CUDA source file ..\..\..\modules\func1\func1.cu...
[build]   
[build]   C:\artemis\artemis_tests\fix_cuda_linker\build\modules\func1>"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.5\bin\nvcc.exe" -gencode=arch=compute_52,code=\"compute_52,compute_52\" -gencode=arch=compute_52,code=\"sm_52,compute_52\" --use-local-env -ccbin "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\bin\HostX64\x64" -x cu -rdc=true   -I"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.5\include"     --keep-dir x64\Debug  -maxrregcount=0  --machine 64 --compile -cudart static -std=c++14 -Xcompiler="/EHsc -Zi -Ob0" -g  -D_WINDOWS -D"CMAKE_INTDIR=\"Debug\"" -D_MBCS -D"CMAKE_INTDIR=\"Debug\"" -Xcompiler "/EHsc /W1 /nologo /Od /FdC:\artemis\artemis_tests\fix_cuda_linker\build\bin\Debug\func1.pdb /FS /Zi /RTC1 /MDd " -o func1.dir\Debug\func1.obj "C:\artemis\artemis_tests\fix_cuda_linker\modules\func1\func1.cu" 
[build]   func1.cu
[build]   
[build]   C:\artemis\artemis_tests\fix_cuda_linker\build\modules\func1>"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.5\bin\nvcc.exe" -dlink -o func1.dir\Debug\func1.device-link.obj -Xcompiler "/EHsc /W1 /nologo /Od /FdC:\artemis\artemis_tests\fix_cuda_linker\build\bin\Debug\func1.pdb /Zi /RTC1 /MDd " -L"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.5\bin/crt" -L"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.5\lib\x64" cudadevrt.lib cudart_static.lib kernel32.lib user32.lib gdi32.lib winspool.lib comdlg32.lib advapi32.lib shell32.lib ole32.lib oleaut32.lib uuid.lib odbc32.lib odbccp32.lib cudart.lib -forward-unknown-to-host-compiler -Wno-deprecated-gpu-targets  -gencode=arch=compute_52,code=compute_52 -gencode=arch=compute_52,code=sm_52  --machine 64 func1.dir\Debug\func1.obj 
[build]   cudadevrt.lib
[build]   cudart_static.lib
[build]   kernel32.lib
[build]   user32.lib
[build]   gdi32.lib
[build]   winspool.lib
[build]   comdlg32.lib
[build]   advapi32.lib
[build]   shell32.lib
[build]   ole32.lib
[build]   oleaut32.lib
[build]   uuid.lib
[build]   odbc32.lib
[build]   odbccp32.lib
[build]   cudart.lib
[build]   func1.obj
[build]   func1.vcxproj -> C:\artemis\artemis_tests\fix_cuda_linker\build\bin\Debug\func1.lib
[build]   Building Custom Rule C:/artemis/artemis_tests/fix_cuda_linker/modules/func2/CMakeLists.txt
[build]   Compiling CUDA source file ..\..\..\modules\func2\func2.cu...
[build]   
[build]   C:\artemis\artemis_tests\fix_cuda_linker\build\modules\func2>"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.5\bin\nvcc.exe" -gencode=arch=compute_52,code=\"compute_52,compute_52\" -gencode=arch=compute_52,code=\"sm_52,compute_52\" --use-local-env -ccbin "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\bin\HostX64\x64" -x cu -rdc=true  -IC:\artemis\artemis_tests\fix_cuda_linker\modules -IC:\artemis\artemis_tests\fix_cuda_linker\build\bin\Debug -I"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.5\include"     --keep-dir x64\Debug  -maxrregcount=0  --machine 64 --compile -cudart static -std=c++14 -Xcompiler="/EHsc -Zi -Ob0" -g  -D_WINDOWS -D"CMAKE_INTDIR=\"Debug\"" -D_MBCS -D"CMAKE_INTDIR=\"Debug\"" -Xcompiler "/EHsc /W1 /nologo /Od /FdC:\artemis\artemis_tests\fix_cuda_linker\build\bin\Debug\func2.pdb /FS /Zi /RTC1 /MDd " -o func2.dir\Debug\func2.obj "C:\artemis\artemis_tests\fix_cuda_linker\modules\func2\func2.cu" 
[build] C:\artemis\artemis_tests\fix_cuda_linker\modules\func1/func1.cuh(11): warning #821-D: extern inline function "test::func1::AddOne" was referenced but not defined [C:\artemis\artemis_tests\fix_cuda_linker\build\modules\func2\func2.vcxproj]
[build]   
[build] C:\artemis\artemis_tests\fix_cuda_linker\modules\func1/func1.cuh(11): warning #821-D: extern inline function "test::func1::AddOne" was referenced but not defined [C:\artemis\artemis_tests\fix_cuda_linker\build\modules\func2\func2.vcxproj]
[build]   
[build]   func2.cu
[build]   
[build]   C:\artemis\artemis_tests\fix_cuda_linker\build\modules\func2>"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.5\bin\nvcc.exe" -dlink -o func2.dir\Debug\func2.device-link.obj -Xcompiler "/EHsc /W1 /nologo /Od /FdC:\artemis\artemis_tests\fix_cuda_linker\build\bin\Debug\func2.pdb /Zi /RTC1 /MDd " -L"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.5\bin/crt" -L"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.5\lib\x64" cudadevrt.lib cudart_static.lib kernel32.lib user32.lib gdi32.lib winspool.lib comdlg32.lib advapi32.lib shell32.lib ole32.lib oleaut32.lib uuid.lib odbc32.lib odbccp32.lib cudart.lib -forward-unknown-to-host-compiler -Wno-deprecated-gpu-targets  -gencode=arch=compute_52,code=compute_52 -gencode=arch=compute_52,code=sm_52  --machine 64 func2.dir\Debug\func2.obj 
[build]   cudadevrt.lib
[build]   cudart_static.lib
[build]   kernel32.lib
[build]   user32.lib
[build]   gdi32.lib
[build]   winspool.lib
[build]   comdlg32.lib
[build]   advapi32.lib
[build]   shell32.lib
[build]   ole32.lib
[build]   oleaut32.lib
[build]   uuid.lib
[build]   odbc32.lib
[build]   odbccp32.lib
[build]   cudart.lib
[build]   func2.obj
[build]   func2.vcxproj -> C:\artemis\artemis_tests\fix_cuda_linker\build\bin\Debug\func2.lib
[build]   Building Custom Rule C:/artemis/artemis_tests/fix_cuda_linker/modules/func3/CMakeLists.txt
[build]   Compiling CUDA source file ..\..\..\modules\func3\func3.cu...
[build]   
[build]   C:\artemis\artemis_tests\fix_cuda_linker\build\modules\func3>"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.5\bin\nvcc.exe" -gencode=arch=compute_52,code=\"compute_52,compute_52\" -gencode=arch=compute_52,code=\"sm_52,compute_52\" --use-local-env -ccbin "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\bin\HostX64\x64" -x cu -rdc=true  -IC:\artemis\artemis_tests\fix_cuda_linker\modules -IC:\artemis\artemis_tests\fix_cuda_linker\build\bin\Debug -I"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.5\include"     --keep-dir x64\Debug  -maxrregcount=0  --machine 64 --compile -cudart static -std=c++14 -Xcompiler="/EHsc -Zi -Ob0" -g  -D_WINDOWS -D"CMAKE_INTDIR=\"Debug\"" -D_MBCS -D"CMAKE_INTDIR=\"Debug\"" -Xcompiler "/EHsc /W1 /nologo /Od /FdC:\artemis\artemis_tests\fix_cuda_linker\build\bin\Debug\func3.pdb /FS /Zi /RTC1 /MDd " -o func3.dir\Debug\func3.obj "C:\artemis\artemis_tests\fix_cuda_linker\modules\func3\func3.cu" 
[build] C:\artemis\artemis_tests\fix_cuda_linker\modules\func1/func1.cuh(11): warning #821-D: extern inline function "test::func1::AddOne" was referenced but not defined [C:\artemis\artemis_tests\fix_cuda_linker\build\modules\func3\func3.vcxproj]
[build]   
[build] C:\artemis\artemis_tests\fix_cuda_linker\modules\func2/func2.cuh(11): warning #821-D: extern inline function "test::func2::AddTwo" was referenced but not defined [C:\artemis\artemis_tests\fix_cuda_linker\build\modules\func3\func3.vcxproj]
[build]   
[build] C:\artemis\artemis_tests\fix_cuda_linker\modules\func1/func1.cuh(11): warning #821-D: extern inline function "test::func1::AddOne" was referenced but not defined [C:\artemis\artemis_tests\fix_cuda_linker\build\modules\func3\func3.vcxproj]
[build]   
[build] C:\artemis\artemis_tests\fix_cuda_linker\modules\func2/func2.cuh(11): warning #821-D: extern inline function "test::func2::AddTwo" was referenced but not defined [C:\artemis\artemis_tests\fix_cuda_linker\build\modules\func3\func3.vcxproj]
[build]   
[build]   func3.cu
[build]   
[build]   C:\artemis\artemis_tests\fix_cuda_linker\build\modules\func3>"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.5\bin\nvcc.exe" -dlink -o func3.dir\Debug\func3.device-link.obj -Xcompiler "/EHsc /W1 /nologo /Od /FdC:\artemis\artemis_tests\fix_cuda_linker\build\bin\Debug\func3.pdb /Zi /RTC1 /MDd " -L"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.5\bin/crt" -L"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.5\lib\x64" cudadevrt.lib cudart_static.lib kernel32.lib user32.lib gdi32.lib winspool.lib comdlg32.lib advapi32.lib shell32.lib ole32.lib oleaut32.lib uuid.lib odbc32.lib odbccp32.lib cudart.lib -forward-unknown-to-host-compiler -Wno-deprecated-gpu-targets  -gencode=arch=compute_52,code=compute_52 -gencode=arch=compute_52,code=sm_52  --machine 64 func3.dir\Debug\func3.obj 
[build]   cudadevrt.lib
[build]   cudart_static.lib
[build]   kernel32.lib
[build]   user32.lib
[build]   gdi32.lib
[build]   winspool.lib
[build]   comdlg32.lib
[build]   advapi32.lib
[build]   shell32.lib
[build]   ole32.lib
[build]   oleaut32.lib
[build]   uuid.lib
[build]   odbc32.lib
[build]   odbccp32.lib
[build]   cudart.lib
[build]   func3.obj
[build]   func3.vcxproj -> C:\artemis\artemis_tests\fix_cuda_linker\build\bin\Debug\func3.lib
[build]   Building Custom Rule C:/artemis/artemis_tests/fix_cuda_linker/apps/CMakeLists.txt
[build]   Compiling CUDA source file ..\..\apps\apps1.cu...
[build]   
[build]   C:\artemis\artemis_tests\fix_cuda_linker\build\apps>"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.5\bin\nvcc.exe" -gencode=arch=compute_52,code=\"compute_52,compute_52\" -gencode=arch=compute_52,code=\"sm_52,compute_52\" --use-local-env -ccbin "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\bin\HostX64\x64" -x cu -rdc=true  -IC:\artemis\artemis_tests\fix_cuda_linker\modules -IC:\artemis\artemis_tests\fix_cuda_linker\build\bin\Debug -I"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.5\include"     --keep-dir x64\Debug  -maxrregcount=0  --machine 64 --compile -cudart static -std=c++14 -Xcompiler="/EHsc -Zi -Ob0" -g  -D_WINDOWS -D"CMAKE_INTDIR=\"Debug\"" -D_MBCS -D"CMAKE_INTDIR=\"Debug\"" -Xcompiler "/EHsc /W1 /nologo /Od /Fdapp1.dir\Debug\vc142.pdb /FS /Zi /RTC1 /MDd " -o app1.dir\Debug\apps1.obj "C:\artemis\artemis_tests\fix_cuda_linker\apps\apps1.cu" 
[build] C:\artemis\artemis_tests\fix_cuda_linker\modules\func3/func3.cuh(11): warning #821-D: extern inline function "test::func3::AddThree" was referenced but not defined [C:\artemis\artemis_tests\fix_cuda_linker\build\apps\app1.vcxproj]
[build]   
[build] C:\artemis\artemis_tests\fix_cuda_linker\modules\func3/func3.cuh(11): warning #821-D: extern inline function "test::func3::AddThree" was referenced but not defined [C:\artemis\artemis_tests\fix_cuda_linker\build\apps\app1.vcxproj]
[build]   
[build]   apps1.cu
[build]   
[build]   C:\artemis\artemis_tests\fix_cuda_linker\build\apps>"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.5\bin\nvcc.exe" -dlink -o app1.dir\Debug\app1.device-link.obj -Xcompiler "/EHsc /W1 /nologo /Od /Fdapp1.dir\Debug\vc142.pdb /Zi /RTC1 /MDd " -L"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.5\bin/crt" -LC:/artemis/artemis_tests/fix_cuda_linker/build/bin -LC:/artemis/artemis_tests/fix_cuda_linker/build/bin/Debug -L"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.5\lib\x64" ..\bin\Debug\func1.lib ..\bin\Debug\func2.lib ..\bin\Debug\func3.lib cudadevrt.lib cudart_static.lib kernel32.lib user32.lib gdi32.lib winspool.lib shell32.lib ole32.lib oleaut32.lib uuid.lib comdlg32.lib advapi32.lib -forward-unknown-to-host-compiler -Wno-deprecated-gpu-targets  -gencode=arch=compute_52,code=compute_52 -gencode=arch=compute_52,code=sm_52  --machine 64 app1.dir\Debug\apps1.obj 
[build] CUDALINK : nvlink error : Undefined reference to '_ZN4test5func38AddThreeEf' in 'app1.dir/Debug/apps1.obj' [C:\artemis\artemis_tests\fix_cuda_linker\build\apps\app1.vcxproj]
[build]   func1.lib
[build]   func2.lib
[build]   func3.lib
[build]   cudadevrt.lib
[build]   cudart_static.lib
[build]   kernel32.lib
[build]   user32.lib
[build]   gdi32.lib
[build]   winspool.lib
[build]   shell32.lib
[build]   ole32.lib
[build]   oleaut32.lib
[build]   uuid.lib
[build]   comdlg32.lib
[build]   advapi32.lib
[build]   apps1.obj
[build] C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\BuildCustomizations\CUDA 11.5.targets(874,9): error MSB3721: The command ""C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.5\bin\nvcc.exe" -dlink -o app1.dir\Debug\app1.device-link.obj -Xcompiler "/EHsc /W1 /nologo /Od /Fdapp1.dir\Debug\vc142.pdb /Zi /RTC1 /MDd " -L"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.5\bin/crt" -LC:/artemis/artemis_tests/fix_cuda_linker/build/bin -LC:/artemis/artemis_tests/fix_cuda_linker/build/bin/Debug -L"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.5\lib\x64" ..\bin\Debug\func1.lib ..\bin\Debug\func2.lib ..\bin\Debug\func3.lib cudadevrt.lib cudart_static.lib kernel32.lib user32.lib gdi32.lib winspool.lib shell32.lib ole32.lib oleaut32.lib uuid.lib comdlg32.lib advapi32.lib -forward-unknown-to-host-compiler -Wno-deprecated-gpu-targets  -gencode=arch=compute_52,code=compute_52 -gencode=arch=compute_52,code=sm_52  --machine 64 app1.dir\Debug\apps1.obj" exited with code 255. [C:\artemis\artemis_tests\fix_cuda_linker\build\apps\app1.vcxproj]
[build] Build finished with exit code 1
```

The folder/file structure looks like this:

```
|   .gitignore
|   CMakeLists.txt
|
+---apps
|       apps1.cu (NOTE: uses func1 func2 func3)
|       CMakeLists.txt
|
+---build (NOTE: I REMOVED LINES HERE)
|
\---modules
    |   CMakeLists.txt
    |
    +---func1
    |       CMakeLists.txt
    |       func1.cu
    |       func1.cuh
    |
    +---func2 (NOTE: uses func1)
    |       CMakeLists.txt
    |       func2.cu
    |       func2.cuh
    |
    \---func3 (NOTE: uses func1 func2)
            CMakeLists.txt
            func3.cu
            func3.cuh
```

and the minimum failing example that I wrote can be found here [on Github](https://github.com/Scoolvac/CMAKE_CUDA_CXX_LINK_ERROR).

While trying to fix this error, I found a lot of old questions (>5y) regarding CUDA CMake linking errors and most of them were solved by enabling separate compilation of device and host code (setting CUDA_SEPARABLE_COMPILATION to ON). Sometimes resolve device symbols (setting CUDA_RESOLVE_DEVICE_SYMBOLS to ON) was required as well since this forces device and host separate compilation already at the start. For me however, none of the combinations for executables and libraries work.

How does this example compile?
Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

So, I have finally managed to compile this dummy project. A working solution for MSVC2019 can be found [here](https://github.com/Scoolvac/CMAKE_CUDA_CXX_LINK_ERROR/tree/working_solution) and the original problem [here](https://github.com/Scoolvac/CMAKE_CUDA_CXX_LINK_ERROR/tree/master).

The solution was to enable CUDA_SEPARABLE_COMPILATION for all files with `__device__` functions and only for files with `__global__` functions also enabling CUDA_RESOLVE_DEVICE_SYMBOLS. Also adding `dummy.cu` files to the project helps CMake identifying CUDA code.

Among many others, these two links helped me finding the answer:

https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/linking-multiple-static-cuda-libs/148964
https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/issues/17520